# Include and Exclude Words in one expression

Tags: regex

I need a regex expression that only searches for the word `size` - **non-case-sensitive**, but excludes `Drawing.size` and `FontSize`

So it could find the words:

```
size
Size
BSize
SizeA
```

but it would exclude the words like:

```
Drawing.size
FontSize
```

Comment: Look for start of string or any word character before. `/(^|\w)size/i` https://regex101.com/r/iD0uS2/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative look ahead to exclude the prefix words:

```
/^(?:(?!(?:Drawing\.|Font)).)*size.*$/im
```

See demo https://regex101.com/r/kV2nR2/1

Note that the flag `i` makes your regex case insensitive and `m` is multiline flag and makes the anchors `^` and `$` match the start and end of the regex for each line.